# How does the piggybacking of current thread variable in ReentrantLock.Sync work?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization, memory-barriers

I read about some of the details of implementation of ReentrantLock in "Java Concurrency in Practice", section 14.6.1, and something in the annotation makes me confused:

> Because the protected state-manipulation methods have the memory semantics of a volatile read or write and ReentrantLock is careful to **read the owner field only after calling getState** and **write it only before calling setState**, ReentrantLock can piggyback on the memory semantics of the synchronization state, and thus avoid further synchronization see Section 16.1.4.

the code which it refers to:

```
protected boolean tryAcquire(int ignored) {
    final Thread current = Thread.currentThread();
    int c = getState();
    if (c ==0) {
        if (compareAndSetState(0, 1)) {
             owner = current;
             return true;
        }
     } else if (current == owner) {
         setState(c+1);
         return true;
     }
     return false;
}
```

And I believe this is the simplified code of the `nonfairTryAcquire` in the `ReentrantLock.Sync`.

```
final boolean nonfairTryAcquire(int acquires) {
    final Thread current = Thread.currentThread();
    int c = getState();
    if (c == 0) {
        if (compareAndSetState(0, acquires)) {
            setExclusiveOwnerThread(current);
            return true;
        }
    }
    else if (current == getExclusiveOwnerThread()) {
        int nextc = c + acquires;
        if (nextc < 0) // overflow
            throw new Error("Maximum lock count exceeded");
        setState(nextc);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

So, the baffling part is how the setting of `owner`, which is merely a plain instance variable in `AbstractOwnableSynchronizer`, becomes visible to `else if (current == owner)` in other threads. Indeed, the read of `owner` is after the calling of `getState()` (and the `state` is a `volatile` qualified variable of `AQS`), but after the setting of `owner`, there's nothing (can impose synchronization semantics) at all. Data race happens?

Well, in light of the authority of this book and the thoroughly tested code, two possibilities come to my mind:

1. The full barrier (be it mfence or 'lock'ed instruction) before the setting `owner = current` does the hidden work. But from I've learned from several famous articles, the full barrier cares more about the writes before it as well as the reads after it. Well, if this possibility holds true, then some sentences in "JCIP" might be inappropriately stated.
2. I notice that 'geographically' the `setState(c+1)` really comes after `owner = current` in the code snippet, although it's in another branch of if-else. If what the comments says is the truth, does it mean that the barrier inserted by `setSate(c+1)` can impose synchronization semantics on `owner = current` in another branch?

I'm a novice in this area, and several great blogs help me a lot in understanding what's underlying the JVM(no ordering):

- http://mechanical-sympathy.blogspot.com/
- http://preshing.com/
- http://bartoszmilewski.com
- http://psy-lob-saw.blogspot.com/

as well as the always magnificent: http://g.oswego.edu/dl/jmm/cookbook.html

After doing my homework and searching the internet, I fail to come to a satisfying conclusion.

Pardon me if this is too wordy or unclear(English is not my mother tongue). Please help me with this, anything related is appreciated.

Comment: You might be interested in "The java.util.concurrent Synchronizer Framework" by Doug Lea. http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/papers/aqs.pdf

Comment: This one is a littel beyond me for now I guess, but I'll try. Thank you @ewernli. And thanks to rolfl for making me release that I should never forget the big(bigger?) picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You suspect there could be a race between `owner = current;` (after the CAS) and `if (current == owner)` (after reading the state and checking if it is >0).

Taking this piece of code in isolation, I think your reasoning is correct. However, you need to consider `tryRelease` as well:

```
 123:         protected final boolean tryRelease(int releases) {
 124:             int c = getState() - releases;
 125:             if (Thread.currentThread() != getExclusiveOwnerThread())
 126:                 throw new IllegalMonitorStateException();
 127:             boolean free = false;
 128:             if (c == 0) {
 129:                 free = true;
 130:                 setExclusiveOwnerThread(null);
 131:             }
 132:             setState(c);
 133:             return free;
 134:         }
```

Here the owner is set to `null` before the state is set to 0. To initially acquire the lock, the state must be 0, and so the owner is `null`.

Consequently,

- If a thread reaches `if (current == owner)` with `c=1`,

  - it can be the owning thread, in which case the owner is correct and the state is incremented.
  - it can be another thread, which can see or not the new owner.

    - If it sees it, everything is fine.
    - If not, it will see `null`, which is fine as well.
- If a thread reaches `if (current == owner)` with `c>1`,

  - it can be the owning thread, in which case the owner is correct and the state is incremented.
  - it can be another thread, but the owner will be correct for sure.

I aggree that the footnote "read the owner field only after calling getState and **write it only before calling setState**" in JCIP is misleading. It writes the `owner` before calling `setState` in `tryRelease`, but not `tryAcquire`.

Comment: Exactly! I will accept your answer. But from the perspective of logic, I also got feeling that rolfl might have some points. Without volatile or piggybakc, the `owner` just stay in a thread's working memory(cache). When certain thread enter into `tryAcquire` and find out that `c != 0` without itself being the 'actual owner', even if the `owner` might be stale or null, there's no chance that the thread will mistakenly consider itself to be the owner, and the contract(protocol) holds. Well of course, if you first `tryAcquire(3)` and then `tryRelease(1)`, the `owner` would definitely be accurate.

Comment: @DarKeViLzAc What is critical, is that when a thread releases the lock (c=0), it sets the owner to null. If it wasn't the case, the following could occur: Initially, c=1 and owner=T1. T1 releases the lock and sets c=0, but does not reset the owner. T2 sets c=1 and owner=T2. T1 attempt to acquire the lock again, it sees c=1 and owner=T1 (because the change from T1 to T2 is not reflected yet). It incorrectly increments the counter, c=2.

Comment: I agree with you, though I still can't help but ask another question: if the `owner` takes no advantage of the volatile state(no piggyback) but still be set to null, will the lock work as expected. Well, just a wild thought, please don't take it too serious.:)

Comment: @DarKeViLzAc I think that it wouldn't work if the owner does not piggyback the volatile state.

Answer (score 1):

This is explained quite well in [this blog post](http://jeremymanson.blogspot.ca/2008/11/what-volatile-means-in-java.html). Bottom line is that when the reading thread reads a volatile field, all fields updated by the writing thread that were modified **before the write to the volatile field** will be visible to the reading thread too. The lock class organizes the field accesses to ensure that only the state field needs to be volatile, and the owner field is still safely propogated when needed

Comment: That's exactly what confuses me: the owner field is updated **after the CAS operation to the volatile field**. The so called piggyback doesn't seem to work here. Thanks for the link though, another one into collection.

Comment: Yes, but the only time the content of the owner field is significant is **after** we know that c != 0, and for that we also know that **we** are the owning thread, and thus we would not have an issue with the state of the variable in the memory model (If we were not the owning thread then there is no way for `owner == Thread.currentThread()`

Comment: I get it. Your explanation makes sense. May be I was too focused on the fence thing, which just narrow my vision and neglect the logical cause. But talking about what I asked above, can you help me to reach a conclusion. More specifically, the text which I reference (in bold), is it kinda misleading? Much appeciated.

Comment: I still don't get it. Another thread could see `c != 0`  and **not** be the owning thread. That's the whole point of the `owner == current` test. I think this synchronization scheme works only if you take tryRelease into consideration (see my answer).